# lodash: array filter and exclude by object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an `Array a` of *Questions*:

```
[
  {id: 1,name: "Question 1"},
  {id: 2,name: "Question 2"},
  {id: 3,name: "Question 3"},
]
```

and an `Array b` of *Answers*, where the property `question_id` references the property `id` of `Array a`:

```
[
  {id: 1, question_id: 2,name: "My Answer to Question 2"}
]
```

With lodash, I want to filter `Array a` to exlude all the *Answers* that are referencing to it, expecting the output:

```
[
  {id: 1,name: "Question 1"},
  {id: 3,name: "Question 3"},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var questions = [
    {id: 1,name: "Question 1"},
    {id: 2,name: "Question 2"},
    {id: 3,name: "Question 3"},
];

var answers = [
    {id: 1, question_id: 2,name: "My Answer to Question 2"}
];

var filtered = _.filter(questions, isNotReferencedByAnyAnswer);

function isNotReferencedByAnyAnswer(question) {
    return _.findIndex(answers, {'question_id': question.id}) === -1;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Just FYI, this can be achieved with vanilla JS only now-a-days. So, if you are loading Lodash just for this, better off with vanilla JS only.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer with [lodash.differenceWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#differenceWith)

```
arr = [
       {id: 1,name: "Question 1"},
       {id: 2,name: "Question 2"},
       {id: 3,name: "Question 3"},
]
arr1 = [
  {id: 1, question_id: 2,name: "My Answer to Question 2"}
]
_.differenceWith(arr, arr1, (arrVal, othVal) => arrVal.id === othVal.question_id)

// result

[ { id: 1, name: 'Question 1' }, { id: 3, name: 'Question 3' } ]
```